# Android repeating alarm which starts after connecting to WiFi

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I would like to show a notification to the user that has some info which I pull from my server.
The notification is sticky and is only shown when connected to Wi-Fi.
The notification needs to be updated every X minutes with the user's new info.

For that, I've created a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, `android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED` and `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE`.
So when the phone boots up, my receiver's `onReceive` will be called.
The receiver checks:
If Wi-Fi is connected: it starts the alarm (using `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating`).
The alarm creates an intent to an `IntentService` and in its `onHandleIntent` it updates the notification content.
If Wi-Fi isn't connected: it stops the alarm using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, InfoNotificationService.class);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pIntent);
```

In order to hide the notification, when the alarm is canceled, I override the `InfoNotificationService` `onDestroy` which hides the notification.

What happens in practice is that the notification is shown again and again even (even when Wi-Fi is not changed) - its `onDestory` and then its `onHandleIntent` are called in an infinite loop.

Calling the `hideNotification` function right after I cancel the alarm (in the receiver) works. But this doesn't seem like the right way. When ever the service dies, I want the notification to be hidden.
What am I doing wrong?